# android gradle build set class attribute value

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I want to set attribute values in my `Application class` from the `build.gradle` file like for example:

```
MyApplication.URL = "someurl.com"
```

that should be determined per build,

I tried :

```
productFlavors {
    myApp {
       qualified.package.path.MyApplication.URL = "someurl.com"
    }
}
```

but it failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your fields inside BuildConfig class and then get them from there.

```
productFlavors {
    myApp {
       buildConfigField "String", "URL", "\"someurl.com\""
    }
}


public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private String URL;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        URL = BuildConfig.URL;
    }   
}
```